# Exist any way to integrate Google Rich Snippets in D6?

Tags: nodes, 6, rating

I have a dilemma with the topic of Google Rich Snippets in drupal 6.
Looking, no module to do so (Yes in Drupal 7, but work with drupal 6) and looking not find any solution. (I use Fivestar on my site)

So my dilemma is whether or, if it can implement this in Drupal 6 ... And that way you can do.

Someone to do? Someone could find a solution? I'm not as expert in Drupal but I want to know whether and in what way. It is urgent.

Thanks :D

Comment: what specifically do you need?  a quick look at this makes me think it is very similar to facebook's open graph meta tags, and if google wants people to implement it widely, pretty simple, too...

Comment: @jimajamma I need to implement Google Rich Snippets in my Drupal site (v 6.x) Because i need, when users search by google the site, in the result show The rating (fivestar) of the products (nodes)

Comment: I mean, what precise snippets are you needing and where in your site

Comment: For example, if you go to http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets what parts of the results shown from the various example urls do you need?

Comment: Ok.. when i put the page in this tool.. I have the following error: "This page does not contain authorship or rich snippet markup"...

Comment: I need implement rich snippet markup in my Drupal Site, how to do it? or what steps i need to follow?

Comment: right, your site doesn't have that information.   if you click on any of the example sites on that page, it will list all kinds of snippets that it supports....what kind do you need your site to support.

Comment: @Jimajamma uuhmmm is a snippets for show the stars of my content product's .. My target is do something like this: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/05/introducing-rich-snippets.html
But, i don't know how to implement this in drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the comments, I am thinking all you'd need to do is theme the fivestar summary with google's snippets.  To do that, I pulled the `theme_fivestar_summary()` out of the module and plopped it into my theme's template.php file like so:

```
function YOURTHEME_fivestar_summary($user_rating, $average_rating, $votes, $stars = 5, $feedback = TRUE) {
  $output = '<span itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">'; // ADDITION #1
  $div_class = '';
  if (isset($user_rating)) {
    $div_class = isset($votes) ? 'user-count' : 'user';
    $user_stars = round(($user_rating * $stars) / 100, 1);
    $output .= '<span class="user-rating">'. t('Your rating: <span>!stars</span>', array('!stars' => $user_rating ? $user_stars : t('None'))) .'</span>';
  }
  if (isset($user_rating) && isset($average_rating)) {
    $output .= ' ';
  }
  if (isset($average_rating)) {
    $div_class = isset($votes) ? 'average-count' : 'average';
    $average_stars = round(($average_rating * $stars) / 100, 1);
    $output .= '<span class="average-rating">'. t('Average: <span itemprop="ratingValue">!stars</span>', array('!stars' => $average_stars)) .'</span>'; // ADDITION #2
  }
  if (isset($user_rating) && isset($average_rating)) {
    $div_class = 'combo';
  }

  if (isset($votes) && !(isset($user_rating) || isset($average_rating))) {
    $output .= ' <span class="total-votes">'. format_plural($votes, '<span itemprop="reviewCount">@count</span> vote', '<span itemprop="reviewCount">@count</span> votes') .'</span>'; // ADDITION #3
    $div_class = 'count';
  }
  elseif (isset($votes)) {
    $output .= ' <span class="total-votes">('. format_plural($votes, '<span itemprop="reviewCount">@count</span> vote', '<span itemprop="reviewCount" >@count</span> votes') .')</span>'; // ADDITION #4
  }

  if ($votes === 0) {
    $output = '<span class="empty">'. t('No votes yet') .'</span>';
  }

  $output = '<div class="fivestar-summary fivestar-summary-'. $div_class . ($feedback ? ' fivestar-feedback-enabled' : '') .'">'. $output .'</div>';
  $output .= '</span>'; // ADDITION #5
  return $output;
}
```

and commented where I added the snippet additions.

Comment: and I don't know how I posted the answer twice but hopefully it will be deleted :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!.. This answer can help me a lot in my project!.. Thanks again :D!